# How can I make my svDialogs::dlg_message appear when run in a background process?

Tags: r, rstudio, background-process

Reprex: Doesn't display a message

```
test <- callr::r_bg(function(){
  Sys.sleep(2)
  svDialogs::dlg_message("msg")
})
```

Also interested in other approaches to get a background process to display pop-up messages.